# Can I use Neo4j Community Edition in production?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, text-search

I'm currently using sql server queries to find the matching text but the speed is not fast enough unfortunately.I'm trying to match the input text to a series of keywords. if the input's words are each like any of the keywords of a certain record, then that record becomes selected.

It seems using a graph database can makes my queries faster.

But:

**Neo4j** Enterprise Edition in my product but it isn't free.
Can I use it's community edition for production?

Or are there other alternatives that I can use instead of Neo4j?

Comment: You should add more details to your question. Questions like "recommend me x" tend to get down-voted unless you provide more details. For example, why are you looking at a graph database ? Do you need horizontal scalability ? Is migration from SQL or JSON important ? Is a schema important to you ? Do you have any language restrictions ? etc ... etc . . . Try to add more details and you will likely get more help.

Comment: @Filipe Teixeira : I think I've provided enough information for you to be able to answer the question. But only one thing may help is that I need a `graph database` to develop a search engine which retrieves information which user needs based on the text he had searched. there are growing records of data which are being `inserted to the db` day by day and `sql server` doesn't seem to provide the speed we need for that.

Comment: @Filipe Teixeira: So could you please tell us can we use community edition of NEO4J?

Comment: The answer I linked merely lists other graph db vendors in answer to `Or are there other alternatives that I can use instead of Neo4j?` . With regards to Neo4J you will have to wait for others to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product licensing question, and should be asked to the vendor specifically. It's not a programming question.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Let's not turn this into a discussion of reasons for product use, or for alternative products.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Apologies, my intention was not that at all. It was merely an attempt to address the 2nd part of the question. Not spark off vendor comparisons. I have removed my comment.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira if you didn't want to answer then why did you ask for clarification

Comment: @MaryamAbbasi Your question is vague and you should not post these kinds of questions on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can continue to use the [Community Edition free in production environments](https://neo4j.com/licensing/), though you will not have access to Enterprise features (including existence constraints, clustered deployments, monitoring features, enterprise-grade locking, hot backups, and [more](https://neo4j.com/editions/)). You cannot however embed neo4j within downloaded applications or code, just use it server-side.

That said, the usages you mentioned seems like your solution is heavy on text searching functionality. I'd recommend looking at search engines such as ElasticSearch, SOLR, or other Lucene-based solutions as something to use on top of an existing db (such as your sql server) to handle those cases. These kinds of solutions are meant to tackle pretty much any problem related to rich textual searches or textual data.

Comment: I'm currently using `sql server` queries to find the matching text but the speed is not fast enough unfortunately.I'm trying to match the input text to a series of keywords. if the input's words are each like any of the keywords of a certain record, then that record becomes selected. Is `ElasticSearch`, or `SOLR` on top of `sql server' faster ? Do you know any faster algorithms for matching the searching text to a collection of keywords?Thx.

Comment: As others have noted, perhaps a specific product recommendation does not belong here. Let me just say that expanding your research to include search engine solutions may prove useful given your use cases. If not, neo4j community edition remains an option currently, but that information should be relatively clear on the vendor site. When researching vendor information, it's best to learn what you can from vendor sites before you come to Stack Overflow with a question about them.